# How to interpret the results of mean and variance to determine the stationarity of time series

Tags: time-series, variance, mean, stationarity, unit-root

After breaking the series into 3 parts and then compute mean and variance for each part. I need to understand what is the acceptable difference between the 3 parts to say this series is stationary?

This is the output for 2 series:

Series1:

```
mean1= 19.079044     mean2= 21.812044    mean3= 18.575845   
variance1= 1.437688  variance2= 1.151551     variance3= 0.547118
```

Series2:

```
mean1= 0.207178  mean2= 0.146585     mean3= -0.333707   
variance1= 0.999076  variance2= 0.950360     variance3= 0.974912
```

I think that the first series is stationary because the difference between the mean is very little, but what about the second series?

This is my code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("C://r3800.txt")  
values = data.values
# getting the count to split the dataset into 3
parts = int(len(values)/3)
# splitting the data into three parts
part_1, part_2, part_3 = values[0:parts], values[parts:(
    parts*2)], values[(parts*2):(parts*3)] 
# calculating the mean of the separated three
# parts of data individually.
mean_1, mean_2, mean_3 = part_1.mean(), part_2.mean(), part_3.mean() 
# calculating the variance of the separated
# three parts of data individually.
var_1, var_2, var_3 = part_1.var(), part_2.var(), part_3.var() 
# printing the mean of three groups
print('mean1= %f\t mean2= %f\t mean3= %f \t' % (mean_1, mean_2, mean_3)) 
# printing the variance of three groups
print('variance1= %f\t variance2= %f \t variance3= %f' % (var_1, var_2, var_3))
```

Comment: On what basis did you split the series?  How long is each part of each series?

Comment: I will share the code

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to say you're splitting them into thirds, with a little overlap at the splits?  Again, *how long are these series?*  That's a crucial piece of information.

Comment: The length is 3800 values

Comment: That indicates the variances are tiny indeed.  But a decision ultimately has to rest on how autocorrelated these series are, too.

Comment: If the mean values are very near to each other and there are different between the variance in this case I base on what?